# Speed up the proces of requesting messages from SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs

We need to process a big number of messages stored in SQS (the messages originate from Amazon store and SQS is the only place we can save them to) and save the result to our database. The problem is, SQS can only return 10 messages at a time. Considering we can have up to 300000 messages in SQS, even if requesting and processing a 10 messages takes little time, the whole process takes forever with the main culprit being actually requesting and receiving the messages from SQS.

We're looking for a way to speed this up. The intended result would be dumping the results to our database. The process would probably run a few times per day (the number of messages would likely be less per run in that scenario).

Comment: Multiple consumer threads? Multiple consumer processes?  Parallel requests to SQS using asynchronous/non-blocking code?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the tip. We figured out we could speed this up by writing async code to do those requests in parallel and I've been codding relentlessly ever since.

Comment: There's the answer.  If you have something that you feel would be useful to future visitors here, please post it as an answer, below.  Otherwise, please consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Michael-sqlbot wrote, parallel requests were the solution. By rewriting our code to use async and making 10 requests at the same time, we managed to reduce the execution time to something much reasonable.

I guess it's because I rarely use multithreading directly in my job, that I haven't thought of using it to solve this problem.